# getting an error during overloading the operations

Tags: c++, linker, unresolved-external

**SOLVED**

I'm writing a code for making Set by linked lists in C++ with visual C++ 2010.
when I want to overload the operations I get this Error

> 1>test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall MySet::MySet(class MySet const &)" (??0MySet@@QAE@ABV0@@Z) referenced in function "public: class MySet __thiscall MySet::operator=(class MySet)" (??4MySet@@QAE?AV0@V0@@Z)

please help me.
how should I get read of this error

Comment: Show us some code. For example, give us the `operator=` and the constructor

Comment: Does your project contain multiple files? If so, explain the structure.

Comment: yes. it is in separate files Set.h and Set.cpp and a setTester.cpp

Comment: The linker is looking for `MySet::operator=(class MySet)`, but cannot find it. In you own answer below, you have it commented out. That would affect the linker...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you declared and defined the following constructor method?

```
MySet::MySet(const MySet &other)
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: after adding copy constructor the problem solved.thank u
because of my rep I cannot upvote ur answer.sorry

Comment: @femchi, you should accept the answer and not upvote it as you raised the question. It is important to accept the answer that solved your problem.